# Generation of symfony form

Tags: php, symfony

After many unsuccessful attempts, I come to you friends.

Entity User.php

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AA\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */ 
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AA\TestBundle\Entity\Themes", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_themes")
*/
protected $themes;
```

Entity Themes.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Themes
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $name;
```

My table themes contains an id and name field with different themes like "sport", "cooking" etc ...

I have my relationship table between theme and user that "user_themes" with two user_id and themes_id fields.

So I would like to display a form giving me the themes of the user, I proceed with the EntityType for now:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('themes', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'        => 'AAUserBundle:User',
    'choice_label' => 'themes',
    'multiple'     => true,
  ))
  ->add('save',      SubmitType::class, array(
    'label' => 'test !'
    ));
}
```

I have the following mistake:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string
```

I understood the error, big themes is an array so it can not display it. Concretely what I would like is to make a themes.name to retrieve the list of themes names of the user.

I really do not know what method to adopt.

Thank you for your help.

Théo.

Comment: did you use the `public function __toString()`?

Comment: yes i've try this but symfony return the same error Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

Comment: and what kind of data is PersistentCollection?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AAUserBundle:User` entity,   should implement a `__toString()` function

otherwise, symfony does not know which property of `AAUserBundle:User` to use,   for display in the selection

alternatively,   set the `choice_name` and `choice_value` options on your formfield

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

I do not see how to implement the toString() method and its interest

Themes being an array, is it possible to make

'choices' => foreach ($ themes as $ themeName) {
...
}

Comment: Sorry i on the Road atm, but i did just notice, that you have your user entry, under the 'class' option, this should be your theme classand instead

Comment: i don't understand, i want just keep the users themes, not all themes

Comment: Yes but you want a drop down, of entities, of the type theme,. Not of the type user ..   (the form uses the user class as data class. But the themes drop down, uses the theme class, as data class),.

Comment: yes it's work with that:   ->add('themes', EntityType::class, array(
   'class'        => 'AATestBundle:Themes',
   'choice_label' => 'name',
   'multiple'     => true,
    )) but that return all themes! I wan't users themes ...

Comment: make sure there are actually themes linked in the database, the the actual user in the form    (if you dump the users themes, ->getThemes or whatever, are they dumped, or is it an empty array ?)   alse double check your setters and getters for user->themes,   and theme->users

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This is how you implement a _toString() function in your entitiy.

```
  public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getthemes();
}
```

Comment: I have implement this method and symfony return the same error. 
    Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string